# Firebase Cloud Functions: What to name parameters when using onCreate() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing my first cloud function. Can someone tell me what is meant by the `{documentId}` parameter in the below code I wrote? Does it need to match code elsewhere or can I use whatever name I want here to name that document?

`sendCommentReportEmail.js`

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

export const sendCommentReportEmail = functions.firestore
  .document('/commentFlags/{documentId}') // <-----what does `{documentId}` mean here and does it need to be verbatim with code elsewhere?
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    try {
      // Get an object representing the document
      // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
      const newDoc = snapshot.data()
      console.log('new doc: ', newDoc)
      console.log('context example: ', context.timestamp)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error in function', error)
    }
    return null
  })
```

Example data in `commentFlags` collection:

```
commentId:
"rZCCJ1VchLJgyllHtZlo"
content:
"test comment again"
photoDocId:
"t3XS4bcfhZ38seCumpuC"
reportedBy:
"bkDhRIax0bMYjvSx2dazI3C2cIJ3"
violator:
"bkDhRIax0bMYjvSx2dazI3C2cIJ3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters), this is called a **wildcard**. It means that the Cloud Function will be triggered for any document created in the `commentFlags` collection.

Within the Cloud Function you can get the value of this wildcard via the `params` object, as shown below. The value corresponds to the ID of the Firestore document that triggered the Cloud Function (i.e. the doc that was created, since you use a `onCreate()` trigger).

```
export const sendCommentReportEmail = functions.firestore
  .document('/commentFlags/{documentId}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const documentId = context.params.documentId;

    // ...
    return ...
})
```

---

> Can I use whatever name I want here to name that document?

Yes, you just need to use the same name when you use the `params` object, as shown above. The only constraints I'm aware of are that the wildcard cannot contain a forward slash (`/`) nor a series of dots, but I would advise to follow the same [constraints than a Firestore document ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).

---

Note that you can have several wildcards in the path, like the following example:

```
exports.globalTriggerer = functions.firestore
    .document('{colId}/{docId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        console.log(context.params.colId);
        console.log(context.params.docId);
        return null;

    });
```

Comment: Thx! Let me study and then I will mark this as answered .